# Update integer in access database through stmt.executeUpdate

Tags: java, ms-access

could someone please help me with formatting my stmt.executeUpdate statement.
below is the basic statement I have used to set the availability of an "Animal" from true to false.(Bool)

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE Animals SET Availability = 'False' WHERE AnimalID = '" + animalId + "'");
```

but would like to know how to format it so that it updates an integer by taking the stocklevel of a "Product" and subtracting a quantity of an order placed by a customer.(Integer)

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE Animals SET Availability = 'stocklevel - quantity' WHERE ProductID = '" + productId + "'");
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: please learn to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Saving aggregate calculations is usually not needed nor advisable. Calculate when needed. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html. How can Availability take a Boolean value in one UPDATE but then a quantity in another?

Comment: Apologies. I meant this.
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE Products SET StockLevel= 'stocklevel - quantity' WHERE ProductID = '" + productId + "'");

Answer (score 0):

By enclosing the new value with single-quotes, your code is currently attempting to set the value of the field to the literal string: `stocklevel - quantity`.

Assuming that `stocklevel` and `quantity` are also fields within the table `Animals`, simply remove such quotes surrounding the value, i.e.:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE Animals SET Availability = stocklevel - quantity WHERE ProductID = '" + productId + "'");
```